# Can I have a file version of Aurelia that is built on save?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, build, aurelia

I am making a Chrome extension using some Chrome API so launching the website from an HTTP server is not feasible. Right now I can do `aurelia build` and refer to the built files in `dist` folder from my extension and side load it.

However, this way, I have to manually run `aurelia build` every time I make some changes. `aurelia run` however, do not create any (visible) file I can see on the hard drive so it's not possible to refer to them during development.

Is there any better setup I can do? Is there a command I don't know that build to a folder whenever I make some changes?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is exactly, but you can't just use `au build --watch` or `au run --watch`?

Comment: Thanks, `au build --watch` is what I needed. Didn't know that argument before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great that you found the solution. In the hope it might help others in the future hereby the answer with two handy commands for use with the Aurelia CLI that help you achieve this.

Automatically (re)build on any file system change and output to the build folder:

```
$ au build --watch
```

Serve the application + automatically (re)build on any file system change:

```
$ au run --watch
```

Further resources:

- [Aurelia CLI docs](https://aurelia.io/docs/cli/basics/)
- [Aurelia CLI GitHub repo](https://github.com/aurelia/cli)

Comment: FYI, in later versions of the CLI, the ```--watch``` flag for ```run``` is redundant because it watches by default